# Applying RegEx on a Hindi sentence

Tags: python, regex, string

I wanted to know how to find the regular expression of finding  :

> "ईरान के अग्रणी विरोधी गुट नेशनल काउंसिल ऑफ रेसिस्टेन्स ईरान के मरयाम
>   रजावी ने यूरोपीय संघ से मांग की कि तेहारान को आतंकवाद और कट्टरपंथी
>   हाइड्रा से मुक्ति दिलानी चाहिए."

in   this sentence :

> "संयुक्त राष्ट्रसंघ महासचिव कोफी अन्नान ने इस पर निराशा जताई तो
>   संयुक्त राष्ट्रसंघ सुरक्षा परिषद् ने एक स्वर से इसकी निंदा की तथा
>   यूरोपियन संघ ने भी कड़े शब्दों में इसकी निंदा की .कनाडा के
>   प्रधानमंत्री मार्टिन ने इसे सीमा रेखा लांघने वाला बताया . ब्रिटेन के
>   प्रधानमंत्री ब्लेयर की नजर में यह खौफनाक है.फ्रांस के विदेशमंत्री
>   फिलिप दोस्ते ब्लेजे ने घोषणा की कि फ्रांस के लिए इजरायल का अस्तित्व
>   टकराव का विषय नहीं है .ली मोन्डे ने इस भाषण को सतर्क होने वाला बताया
>   Die welt ने इसे उच्चरित आतंकवाद बताया तथा लंदन सन् के समाचार शीर्षक
>   में अहमदीनेजाद को विश्व का सबसे बुरा व्यक्ति कहा गया . इस बयान की
>   निंदा करने वाले राज्यों में तुर्की , रुस और चीन भी शामिल हैं. ईरान के
>   अग्रणी विरोधी गुट नेशनल काउंसिल ऑफ रेसिस्टेन्स ईरान के मरयाम रजावी ने
>   यूरोपीय संघ से मांग की कि तेहारान को आतंकवाद और कट्टरपंथी हाइड्रा से
>   मुक्ति दिलानी चाहिए."

I tried using (.star)(sentence)(.star) in python i.e.

```
   reg = re.search(re.escape('.*'+<sentence>+'.*'),<paragraph>)
```

but it is not working.

I have used re.escape() for skipping special characters.

This is encoded in UTF-16.

Is there anything like it can not match sentences other than ascii?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be passing the metacharacters that you *want* the regex engine to understand, resulting in a pattern that you will never find in the string. This will work:

```
In [101]: re.search(p, t)
Out[101]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(656, 823), match='ईरान के अग्रणी विरोधी गुट नेशनल काउंसिल ऑफ रेसिस्>
```

Where `p` is the sentence and `t` is the paragraph.